# Invalid XML character(Unicode: 0x0) Error - Solving the Problem

Tags: java, xml, special-characters

After parsing a number of XML files using Java, I'm getting an

`XMLStreamException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.`

If anyone has ever come across this message, and you had prior knowledge your file should have been encoded correctly upon save (perhaps file corruption happened unexpectedly to 1 of hundreds of files), how would you track down the cause of the error in the file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting my answer to this question. This is the simplest way I've found to handle the issue. I have not tested it.

Jump into a shell and type:

`tr < badfile.xml > other.xml`

...creating a file called other.xml that contains no nulls. Then type 
`cmp other.xml badfile.xml`
 to get the line number of the location of the offending null in the bad file.

Finally use a text editor that reveals these things intermixed in text, to locate in the bad file the offending null character. Two examples of text editors that do this are Emacs or Vim.

Then edit the character out, or determine whether you encoded improperly in the first place.